# Any way to complete an assignment by save editing or console commands?

Tags: mass-effect

I completed Feros before grabbing the freelancer's data, so now I can't complete the assignment. Is there any way to complete that assignment with console commands or by editing the save?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used a console in Mass Effect, but I'm wondering, could you not just go back to pick it up? If I recall, ME is pretty good at allowing you to go back for the most part... From the [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Feros:_Data_Recovery):

> If returning to the facility after finishing the other business on Feros, the data can be accessed by entering the corridor previously blocked by an energy field. Turn left in the first room, and climb the stairs to find the data.

And how to hand in:

> If Zhu's Hope has not already been returned to, Gavin can be found at his original location. If Zhu's Hope has already been returned to, he can be found in the Zhu's Hope courtyard.

Comment: According to the wiki, "However, you will not have access to the Prothean Skyway, and therefore the Exogeni facility, after the main Feros assignment has been completed, and thus will be unable to obtain Gavin's data to finish the assignment." So I can't get back to the room with the data.

Comment: Ah, didn't read that far down - kind of seems like something to put in the main content. Apologies for that, not too sure how else it can be  completed. Hoping someone else from the community knows of an alternative method.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I could try clipping through the skyway barrier with commands and getting the data that way. I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: Success!!! After turning off collisions, I found a floating elevator, and on the other side was the skyway. From there, it was just smooth sailing.

Comment: @Eublepharis you can post your findings as answer